# node.js Iterate through an array in intervall for certain times

Tags: arrays, node.js, loops, httprequest, settimeout

I've been working on node.js for a short time and currently have the following problem: I would like to iterate through an array and send an http request for each element in the array. These requests should be executed every 5 seconds. In addition to this, this should be done max. 10 times.

That means every 5 seconds an http request should be sent for all elements in the array.

I have already tried a branched async for and for each loop, but I am not getting the desired result.

I know where the problem is with my code but can't find another solution.

It looks something like this:

```
// Set for loop
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
   setTimeout(function () {
   // Iterate through every element within the array
   sendItems.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
   // Some code
   request (.....)

   // Exit condition
   if (sendItems[sendItems.length - 1].status === 'Failed'|||
      sendItems[sendItems.length - 1].status ==='Successful') {
        if (cbFlag === false) {
           interval = 0;
            resolve(sendItems);
          }
     }
   });
}interval * i);
```

Comment: `request(.....)`, is this sync or async? Does the loop work properly without `setTimeout`?

Comment: Hello, this is an async loop. It works so far. That means every 5 seconds it is iterated through the elements of the array. what doesn't work is the abort condition. Although I call the resolve(), the remaining iterations of the for loop are performed, including the forEach loop.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly. `cbFlag` is determined elsewhere but once it's false you call `resolve(sendItems)` which should return a list to the promise. However, the loop is already on the thread and since it is resolved in the timeout there is no `break` telling the loop to stop doing the calls. Have you tried setting a flag, calling `break`, then resolving the promise?

Comment: The cbFlag was initially used to terminate the for loop with a breaks() as soon as the forEach loop calls resolve(). But when executing the script I got the message that this is not possible. According to an article on stackoverflow, it is because this is not possible in an async loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by `request` you're referring to the nodejs module. Here a possible solution using something strange like a `sleep` :)

```
const request = require('request');
const _request = require('util').promisify(request);
let sendItems = [1,2,3];

let sleep = (ms) => {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log(`waiting ${ms/1000} sec..`)
                resolve();
            }, ms);
        })
}   
(async function loop() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        for (let id of sendItems) {
            let r = await  _request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'+id, { json: true })
            console.log(r.body.id);
        }
        await sleep(5000);
    } console.log("ok that's it")
})();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try your way. And yes, you were right about the request =)

Comment: Using an IIFE to send the request... Nice.

Comment: @Callat what do yo mean :)? are you sarcastic?

Comment: No I upvoted your implementation, `(async function loop () {...})();` is an immediately invoked function expression right? I just found it pretty nifty for this sample to initiate the call that way instead of just having `loop()` at the bottom. :)

Comment: ah ok, I thought you were sarcastic because that's not the unusual things in my code, or maybe someone would say it's not the best option autocall a remote request. I think the "fun" part here is a javascript `sleep`  :)